# IPv6 routing Public to a subnetwork

Tags: routing, ipv6, router

Doing Linux/Debian IPV6 Routing from my vendor to a client not working.
IPV4 NAT/routing is reliably working using `iptables` and `dnsmasq`, however, even with forwarding enabled on IPv6 I can't make it work.
RADVD is publishing the new network but, I can't access any public IPv6 address.

Simplified diagram

```
                                        SW
                                         |    +---------+
                                         +--->| client  |
             PUBLIC              PRIVATE |    +---------+
                                         |
    ~/-(PR)-+       +---(ER)---+         | C0 +--(CL)---+
     public |P0  E0 | extender | E1      +--->| client  |
     vendor |<----->|  router  |<------->|    +---------+
            |       +----------+         |
 ~/---------+                            |    +---------+
                                         +--->| client  |
                                         |    +---------+

 Where:
    PR ISP Public router
       P0 Public network interface
    ER extender router Debian based, trying to configure
       E0 Public network interface
       E1 Private network interface
    CL Test Client
       C0 Private network interface
```

Using `radvdump`, ER shows public route (redacted addresses)

```
    ...
    route 2600:..:5b10::/60
    {
            AdvRoutePreference high;
            AdvRouteLifetime 1209600;
    }; # End of route definition
```

On ER using `radvd` I'm publishing a new /64 network on E1 (2600:..:5b11)
CL received the published network and configure itself with a global address on the 2600:..:5b11 network.
ER can ping6 and connect to: ipv6.google.com, P0, E0, E1 and C0
CL can ping6 and connect to: E0 and E1, but ..not.. P0 (nor any public addresses)

On ER->E1 `tcpdump` shows ER's periodic router advertisement.
When I ping a public address on CL this is the capture on ER-E1:

```
fe80::..:d477 is ER-E1
fe80::..:dff6 and 2600:..:5b11:..:f48 are CL-C0
fe80::..:f380 is PR-p0
2607:f8b0:4002:c0c::8a is ipv6.google.com

IP6 fe80::..:d477 > ff02::1: ICMP6, router advertisement, length 56
IP6 2600:..:5b11:..:f48 > 2607:f8b0:4002:c0c::8a: ICMP6, echo request, seq 1, length 64
IP6 fe80::..:dff6 > fe80::..:d477: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has fe80::..:d477, length 32
IP6 fe80::..:d477 > fe80::..:dff6: ICMP6, neighbor advertisement, tgt is fe80::..:d477, length 24
IP6 fe80::..:d477 > fe80::..:dff6: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has fe80::..:dff6, length 32
IP6 fe80::..:dff6 > fe80::..:d477: ICMP6, neighbor advertisement, tgt is fe80::..:dff6, length 24
IP6 fe80::..:d477 > ff02::1: ICMP6, router advertisement, length 56
```

Ping on CL just hung (until timeout) with no message.

On ER->E0 `tcpdump` (simplified):

```
IP6 2600:..:5b11:..:f48 > 2607:f8b0:4002:c0c::8a: ICMP6, echo request, seq 1, length 64
IP6 fe80::..:c446 > fe80::19d7:1db3:c381:23a: ICMP6, neighbor advertisement, tgt is fe80::..:c446, length 24
IP6 fe80::..:c446 > fe80::..:f380: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has fe80::..:f380, length 32
IP6 fe80::..:f380 > fe80::..:c446: ICMP6, neighbor advertisement, tgt is fe80::..:f380, length 24
IP6 fe80::..:f380 > fe80::..:c446: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has fe80::..:c446, length 32
IP6 fe80::..:c446 > fe80::..:f380: ICMP6, neighbor advertisement, tgt is fe80::..:c446, length 24
```

ER routing table (eth0=E0 eth1=E1)

```
2600:..:5b10::13 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256  pref medium
2600:..:5b10::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256  expires 1209445sec pref medium
2600:..:5b10::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 303  mtu 1500 pref medium
2600:..:5b11::/64 dev eth1 proto kernel metric 256  pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256  pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth1 proto kernel metric 256  pref medium
default via fe80::..:f380 dev eth0 metric 303  mtu 1500 pref medium
default via fe80::..:f380 dev eth0 proto ra metric 1024  expires 1645sec hoplimit 64 pref medium
```

There are no firewalls involved at this time, not even ip6tables.

On ER I have forwarding=1 and proxy_ndp=1 for all and default.

Comment: What does `ip6tables -L -vn` look like on the router? Is the IPv6 FORWARD table dropping everything?

Comment: @telcoM  INPUT,OUTPUT,FORWARD set to ACCEPT.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the ping echo request is arriving on E1 and going out on E0, so on ER, everything works as it should.

However, you have a problem on PR: when the ping echo reply arrives, it will have a destination address of `2600:...:5b11:...:f48`. However, PR only knows about the `5b10/60` subnet behind P0, it has no idea that there also is a `5b11/64` subnet reachable via E0. So my *guess* (one would have to verify this on the interface dumps) is that PR does a neighbour solication for `2600:...:5b11:...:f48` on P0, but ER doesn't answer (because it doesn't own this address), so PR drops the packet.

I've never tried to set up IPv6 with a contained subnet this way, so I'm not sure what to recommend. First thing I'd try is to also advertise the `5b11/64` on E0, and see if this additional information makes P0 forward the packets.

**Edit**

I found [ndppd](https://github.com/DanielAdolfsson/ndppd), the neighbour discovery protocol proxy demon. If PR indeed sends a neughbour solicitation for which it gets no answer, using ndppd on ER might solve this problem.

I haven't used it myself yet.

Comment: Your assessment is right PR is blind: from a client I can't ping P0. I tried to use the same network (5b10), also with radvd publish '5b11' on E0 (and E1): no luck. Do you suggest  a better method to publish the public network to the client?

Comment: Can you control PR in any way? For example, can you set routes?

Comment: It's a vendor (Comcast) device, I don't think so, no option on web settings, and will not be a generic solution. Looks like publishing routes doesn't work either.
`ndppd` looks like a good idea but I can't make it work.